# How to set context for a shortcut?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can assign a key to a shortcut, however, I cannot specify its context as shown below:

[image]

<kbd>L</kbd> key has a context of `Shortcut Context`. This one is defined by Unity.

I've assigned <kbd>;</kbd> key, however the context is empty.

I would like to use the same context as for the <kbd>L</kbd> key.

Basically, all you can do is assign a global shortcut...

There doesn't seem to be any option for doing this in the UI.

Any ideas?